# Check if user uploaded a photo in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to get user's photo but if I'm using `PhotoUrl` field, I'm getting the default photo.
So I want to know if a user doesn't have his own photo and then not use the default one but a custom of my own.

Is there a way to detect that kind of thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a user with a stock photo will have a photo url containing the value `/005/T`, while a user with a custom photo will not. I'm not sure where this is documented, or if it could change, but I believe that's the best we have to go off of right now.